# browserSync stopped injecting css

Tags: webpack, gulp, browser-sync

I've used this gulp file for a couple of months without a problem. But out of the blue it stopped injecting css on all my projects.

I've tried to reinstall all packages but nothing changes. How can I find out what the cause of this is?

```
import { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } from 'gulp';
import yargs from 'yargs';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import cleanCss from 'gulp-clean-css';
import gulpif from 'gulp-if';
import postcss from 'gulp-postcss';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import del from 'del';
import webpack from 'webpack-stream';
import named from 'vinyl-named';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import info from './package.json';

const PRODUCTION = yargs.argv.prod;
const server = browserSync.create();


// Live load and reload changes
export const serve = done => {
  server.init({
    port: 3000,
    server: true
  });
  done();
};

export const reload = done => {
  server.reload();
  done();
};


// Clean dist folder
export const clean = () => del(['dist']);


// Bundle styles
export const styles = () => {
  return src(['src/scss/main.scss'])
  .pipe(gulpif(!PRODUCTION, sourcemaps.init()))
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulpif(PRODUCTION, postcss([ autoprefixer ])))
  .pipe(gulpif(PRODUCTION, cleanCss({compatibility:'ie8'})))
  .pipe(gulpif(!PRODUCTION, sourcemaps.write()))
  .pipe(dest('dist/css'))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}


// Copy new folders to dist
export const copy = () => {
  return src(['src/**/*','!src/{images,js,scss}','!src/{images,js,scss}/**/*'])
  .pipe(dest('dist'));
}


// Bundle scripts
export const scripts = () => {
...
}


// Watch for changes
export const watchForChanges = () => {
  watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', styles);
  watch('src/images/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif}', series( reload));
  watch(['src/**/*','!src/{js,scss}','!src/{js,scss}/**/*'], series(copy, reload));
  watch('src/js/**/*.js', series(scripts, reload));
  watch('**/*.php', reload);
  watch('**/*.html', reload);
}


// Tasks
export const dev = series(clean, parallel(styles, copy, scripts), serve, watchForChanges);
export const build = series(clean, parallel(styles, copy, scripts));
export default dev;
```

The CSS get's loaded like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/main.css">`

The terminal outputs:
23:11:38 Starting 'styles'...
23:11:38 Finished 'styles' after 33 ms

Comment: Are you in prod env ?

Comment: @Jean-NicolasG. Yes I am